# Exporting specific cells to a csv file - can't get it to run through rows

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I've got an issue with my code. It's supposed to run in a file I download each month and export a subset of that data to a csv I can use.
This is my code.

```
Sub Eksporter()
Dim whatever As String
file = FreeFile
filepath = ""
Filename = filepath & "X" & ".csv"
Open Filename For Output As #file
For row = 2 To 10000
whatever = Cells(row, 3) & ";;" & Cells(row, 12) & vbNewLine
Next row
Print #file, whatever
Close #file
End Sub
```

It runs alright, but only does row 2 before it stops. Any ideas? Any other ways of doing this? I'm an amateur to all of this so any tips appreciated.

Comment: I suspect it works, but only seems to do the last row.  You are overwriting whatever each time.  Change your code to `whatever = whatever & Cells(row, 3) ... `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way, fill an array and use [Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/join-function) to create the string.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Eksporter()

    Const filepath = ""

    Dim ws As Worksheet, ff, filename as String
    Dim LastRow As Long, r As Long, ar() As String

    ' read into array
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    With ws
        LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).row
        ReDim ar(0 To LastRow - 2) ' size the array
        For r = 2 To LastRow
            ar(r - 2) = .Cells(r, "C") & ";;" & .Cells(r, "L")
        Next
    End With

    ' output array to file
    filename = "X_" & Format(Now, "yyyymmdd_HHMMSS") & ".csv"
    ff = FreeFile
    Open filepath & filename For Output As #ff
    Print #ff, Join(ar, vbNewLine)
    Close #ff
    MsgBox LastRow - 1 & " rows exported to " & filepath & filename

End Sub
```